# Method for parsing text Cc field of email header?

Tags: python, parsing, email, email-headers

I have the plain text of a Cc header field that looks like so:

`friend@email.com, John Smith <john.smith@email.com>,"Smith, Jane" <jane.smith@uconn.edu>`

Are there any battle tested modules for parsing this properly?

(bonus if it's in python! the email module just returns the raw text without any methods for splitting it, AFAIK)
(also bonus if it splits name and address into to fields)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are a bunch of function available as a standard python module, but I think you're looking for
[email.utils.parseaddr()](http://docs.python.org/library/email.util.html#email.utils.getaddresses) or [email.utils.getaddresses()](http://docs.python.org/library/email.util.html#email.utils.parseaddr%20email.utils.parseaddr)

```
>>> addresses = 'friend@email.com, John Smith <john.smith@email.com>,"Smith, Jane" <jane.smith@uconn.edu>'
>>> email.utils.getaddresses([addresses])
[('', 'friend@email.com'), ('John Smith', 'john.smith@email.com'), ('Smith, Jane', 'jane.smith@uconn.edu')]
```

Comment: These modules work great, but they both require you to already have your addresses split into individual strings.

Comment: `[ email.utils.parseaddr(a) for a in m.split(',') ]` Where `alist` is the address-list you posted above.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: The name for the 3rd address contains a comma, so that doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that after I posted that. Did some further reading and careful re-reading of the ``email.utils.getaddresses()`` documentation revealed that you need to pass a **list**, not a **string**, do'h! So use ``email.utils.parseaddr([alist])``

Comment: Yes, therein lies the problem that the OP seeks a solution to. The fact that "the email module just returns the raw text without any methods for splitting it" :)

Comment: I'm confused, split what into what?

Comment: Splitting a string containing a list of addresses into a list containing address strings.

Comment: Oh! `getaddresses()` doesn't need a list of strings! .. you can just pass it a list with a single string in it containing multiple addresses. I feel stupid now..

Comment: haha, you should feel smart for taking an interest and learning something new :-) My description above wasn't to clear I guess ...

Comment: Almost too good to be true. Thanks [Jonathan Berger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/518222/jonathan-berger)!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it myself, but it looks to me like you could use the [csv](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) package quite easily to parse the data.

Answer (score 0):

*The bellow is completely unnecessary. I wrote it before realising that you could pass `getaddresses()` a list containing a single string containing multiple addresses.*

I haven't had a chance to look at the specifications for addresses in email headers, but based on the string you provided, this code should do the job splitting it into a list, making sure to ignore commas if they are within quotes (and therefore part of a name).

```
from email.utils import getaddresses

addrstring = ',friend@email.com, John Smith <john.smith@email.com>,"Smith, Jane" <jane.smith@uconn.edu>,'

def addrparser(addrstring):
    addrlist = ['']
    quoted = False

    # ignore comma at beginning or end
    addrstring = addrstring.strip(',')

    for char in addrstring:
        if char == '"':
            # toggle quoted mode
            quoted = not quoted
            addrlist[-1] += char
        # a comma outside of quotes means a new address
        elif char == ',' and not quoted:
            addrlist.append('')
        # anything else is the next letter of the current address
        else:
            addrlist[-1] += char

    return getaddresses(addrlist)

print addrparser(addrstring)
```

**Gives:**

```
[('', 'friend@email.com'), ('John Smith', 'john.smith@email.com'),
 ('Smith, Jane', 'jane.smith@uconn.edu')]
```

I'd be interested to see how other people would go about this problem!

Answer (score 0):

Convert multiple E-mail string in to dictionary (Multiple E-Mail with name in to one string).

```
emailstring = 'Friends <friend@email.com>, John Smith <john.smith@email.com>,"Smith" <jane.smith@uconn.edu>'
```

Split string by Comma

`email_list = emailstring.split(',')`

name is key and email is value and make  dictionary.

```
email_dict = dict(map(lambda x: email.utils.parseaddr(x), email_list))
```

**Result like this:**

```
{'John Smith': 'john.smith@email.com', 'Friends': 'friend@email.com', 'Smith': 'jane.smith@uconn.edu'}
```

**Note:**

If there is same name with different email id then one record is skip.

```
'Friends <friend@email.com>, John Smith <john.smith@email.com>,"Smith" <jane.smith@uconn.edu>, Friends <friend_co@email.com>'
```

"Friends" is duplicate 2 time.

Comment: The parser needs to handle addresses that have a comma in the name - e.g. "Smith, Jane", as that is a valid name for an email address. The emailstring.split(',') command will split up the "Smith, Jane" name into two separate addresses.