# Regex pattern matching unexpected value

Tags: python, regex

I am using following python regex code to analyze values from the To field of an email:

```
import re

PATTERN = re.compile(r'''((?:[^(;|,)"']|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')+)''')
list = PATTERN.split(raw)[1::2]
```

The list should output the name and address of each recipient, based on either "," or ";" as seperator. If these values are within quotes, they are to be ignorded, this is part of the name, often: "Last Name, First Name"

Most of the times this works well, however in the following case I am getting unexpected behaviour:

```
"Some Name | Company Name" <name@example.com>
```

In this case it is splitting on the "|" character. Even though when I check the pattern on regex tester websites, it selects the name and address as a whole. What am I doing wrong?

Example input would be:

```
"Some Name | Company Name" <name1@example.com>, "Some Other Name | Company Name" <name2@example.com>, "Last Name, First Name" <name3@example.com>
```

Comment: It doesn't split anywhere. Gives me an output `['"Some Name | Company Name" <name@example.com>']`

Comment: That's correct, normally there would be multiple of these in a string. I want to single them out. However if I run it on my google app engine, it splits on the |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a direct answer to your question but to the problem you seem to be solving and therefore maybe still helpful:

To parse emails I always make extensive use of Python's [email library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.html).

In your case you could use something like this:

```
from email.utils import getaddresses
from email import message_from_string

msg = message_from_string(str_with_msg_source)
tos = msg.get_all('to', [])
ccs = msg.get_all('cc', [])
resent_tos = msg.get_all('resent-to', [])
resent_ccs = msg.get_all('resent-cc', [])
all_recipients = getaddresses(tos + ccs + resent_tos + resent_ccs)
for (name, address) in all_recipients:
    # do some postprocessing on name or address if necessary
```

This always took reliable care of splitting names and addresses in mail headers in my cases.

Comment: This seems like a great suggestion. I am using a webhook to parse the emails. Can I also feed the string value from a To-field this?

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly. But if you ask whether you can use this for single strings, then yes, sure, e.g.: `email.utils.parseaddr('"Mr Smith | Something" <smith@example.com>')` gives you `('Mr Smith | Something', 'smith@example.com')`.

Comment: Got it. Found the answer based on this here as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5426789/method-for-parsing-text-cc-field-of-email-header

Answer (score 1):

You can use a much simpler regex using look arounds to split the text.

```
r'(?<=>)\s*,\s*(?=")'
```

**Regex Explanation**

- `\s*,\s*` matches `,` which is surrounded by zero or more spaces (`\s*`)
- `(?<=>)` Look behind assertion. Checks if the `,` is preceded by a `>`
- `(?=")` Look ahead assertion. Checks if the `,` is followed by a `"`

**Test**

```
>>> re.split(r'(?<=>)\s*,\s*(?=")', string)
['"Some Name | Company Name" <name1@example.com>', '"Some Other Name | Company Name" <name2@example.com>', '"Last Name, First Name" <name3@example.com>']
```

**Corrections**

- **Case 1** In the above example, we used a single delimiter `,`. If yo wish to split on basis of more than one delimiters you can use a character class

  ```
  r'(?<=>)\s*[,;]\s*(?=")'
  ```

  - `[,;]` Character class, matches `,` or `;`

---

- **Case 2** As mentioned in comments, if the address part is missing, all we need to do is to add `"` to the look behind

  **Example**

  ```
  >>> string = '"Some Other Name | Company Name" <name2@example.com>, "Some Name, Nothing", "Last Name, First Name" <name3@example.com>' 

  >>> re.split(r'(?<=(?:>|"))\s*[,;]\s*(?=")', string)
  ['"Some Other Name | Company Name" <name2@example.com>', '"Some Name, Nothing"', '"Last Name, First Name" <name3@example.com>']
  ```

Comment: For this case yes, but sometimes there is no name included, and just "name@example.com" without the <>. Therefore I figured would need to split on all , or ; outside of quotes

Comment: @Vincent That can also be done. In which case modify the look behind as `(?<=(>|")` so that it looks for `>` or `"` before the `,`

Comment: @Vincent I have added an edit. Do see the case 2 section. I hope that is what you are talking about

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Final question: what do I include to match if it is a single email address without quotes?

Comment: So this would be the final example string: ''"Some Other Name | Company Name" <name2@example.com>, "Some Name, Nothing", <name4@example.com>, name5@example.com, "Last Name, First Name" <name3@example.com>'

Comment: And I noticed your suggestion has some loose "<" and '"' in there. Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: @Vincent Sorry about that, It was because of the capturing groups( the `,` and `>`) I have corected that one in the answer.

Comment: @Vincent I think your second example splits fine with the last regex in case 2.

Comment: I just tried it with a single address and unfortunately it returns an empty list. I also just noticed that some email providers return names in single quotes. I guess it would make sense to check out Myke's suggestion on the included email library in Python, as there are probably more exceptions I don't know about. Neverthless thanks a lot for your help!